# How to verify new user matches pre-existing data when he signs in using Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm working with a business that generates business leads through some Facebook advice/discussion groups they operated. When users start to interact a lot on the group, company managers take note of the users Facebook ID (i.e. "100007223113753") and store it in the company database, to take notes about user's contributions, interest, interactions with the company salespeople, etc.

The company is building an online system now that will allow users to log in to the new system using Facebook's OpenId. They want logged in users to be able to see all the data that has been accumulated about their activity.

Thus, they want a new user who signs in with Facebook, to automatically be connected to the account that has already been created in their name by managers. **How can the system safely verify that the new user matches the ID stored?**

Currently the user data is only returned to the UI but not to our server. We don't want to leave it up to the frontend to inform the backend that the user ID matches, as this presents a major security hole. How we verify the user IDs match directly at the server level?

Comment: call the facebook api server side, with the user token of the logged in user

Comment: @luschn ahh didn't think of that. So I could technically store the user's token and do things with it even while the user is not actively using my app?

Comment: well, yes, or you can transfer the token from client to server all the time. be aware that user tokens are valid for 2 hours only, extended ones for 2 months.